# hibernate is giving me - "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: hibernate_hbm.xml.UserDetails.hbm.xml not found

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I am working with hibernate. I create a table called UserDetails (POJO class) with id and name. I am however finding it difficult to execute the program because it is giving me this error -

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: 
hibernate_hbm.xml.UserDetails.hbm.xml not found
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:740)
    at 
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:2197)
    at 
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:2169)
   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2149)
   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2102)
   at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2017)
   at hibernate_hbm.xml.A.main(A.java:19)
```

All the files are in - hibernate_hbm.xml package -my files are :

[1] UserDetails-

```
package hibernate_hbm.xml;


public class UserDetails {


  private int id;
  private String name;

 //setter & getters        

 }
```

[2]A.java file that contains the UserDetails Objects and SessionFactory -

```
package hibernate_hbm.xml;

 import org.hibernate.Session;
  import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
  import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

 public class A {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    UserDetails user1 = new UserDetails();
    user1.setId(101);
    user1.setName("Mark");

    UserDetails user2 = new UserDetails();
    user2.setId(102);
    user2.setName("Cynthiya");

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user1);
    session.save(user2);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();

    }

 }
```

[3]hibernate.cfg.xml-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property 
   name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property>
  name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql:
  //localhost:3306/testingcampus</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property 
   name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property 
   name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping resource="hibernate_hbm.xml.UserDetails.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

[4] UserDetails.hbm.xml  file -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
   <class name="hibernate_hbm.xml.UserDetails" table="UserInfo">
   <id name="id"></id>
  <property name="name"></property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: If you have a resource `UserDetails.hbm.xml` in the package `hibernate_hbm.xml`, its resource path should be `hibernate_hbm/xml/UserDetails.hbm.xml` instead of `hibernate_hbm.xml.UserDetails.hbm.xml` (in `hibernate.cfg.xml`)

Comment: @Alex  I entered - <class name="hibernate_hbm.xml.UserDetails.hbm.xml" table="UserInfo"> in  UserDetails.hbm.xml file and <mapping resource="hibernate_hbm/xml/UserDetails.hbm.xml" /> in hibernate.cfg.xml file. It is showing error - Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: class hibernate_hbm.xml.UserDetails.hbm.xml not found while looking for property: id  AND Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hibernate_hbm.xml.UserDetails.hbm.xml

Answer (score 0):

As that file is on class path try the mapping resource value in hibernate.cfg.xml as below :

"classpath:UserDetails.hbm.xml"

```
<mapping resource="classpath:UserDetails.hbm.xml" />
```

Do share the folder structure that you followed as that'll help with the exact path to be used

Comment: --> folder structure is :hibernate_hbm.xml>>src>>hibernate_hbm.xml>A.java>UserDetails.java>UserDetails.hbm.xml

Comment: Please format your folder structure using markdown tags

Comment: @Alex  Starting with Project  >hibernate_hbm.xml> src > hibernate3 > A.java & UserDetails.java &UserDetails.hbm.xml > hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: @java_jazz You can actually edit your original post to add any missing / requested information; this is the recommended way, as opposed to putting it in comments. Also, please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help on helpful formatting options (basically, when showing folder structure, format it the same way as a code block, for better readability)